# Why does my column number for function 2 offset when I combine it with function 1?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to come up with a script that does these 2 things in order when called from a 'On form submit' trigger:

1. Adds a sequential ID number to the first column of a row of newly submitted Google Form data,
2. Sends information from this row via email.

I have two separate scripts for each that work great on their own, but when I try to run them together, the column numbers in the 2nd script become offset by -1, meaning ncDate is displayed in the email as ncID, ncType is displayed as ncDate, etc.

I've tried combining the two scripts in this manner:

```
function assignID(e) {
  var sheetID = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var colID =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getLastRow();

  sheetID.getRange(colID,1).setValue(colID);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  sendEmail(e.range);
}


function sendEmail(range) {
  var values = range.getValues();
  var col = values[0];

  var ncID = col[0];
  var ncDate = col[1];
  var ncType = col[2];
  var ncLocation = col[3];
  var ncJobNo = col[4];
  var ncPartNo = col[5];
  var ncPartDesc = col[6];
  var ncPartQty = col[7];
  var ncDetails = col[8];
  var ncPhotos = col[9];
  var ncProposedSol = col[10];
  var ncEmail = col[11];

  var emailRecipients = "test@email.com";
  var emailSubject = ncID+": "+ncType+" ("+ncEmail+")";
  var emailBody = "<h3>Here is the latest issue "+ncEmail+":</h3><hr /> \
  <p> \
  <h1 style='line-height:90%'>"+ncType+": "+ncLocation+"<br /> \
  <span style='font-size:60%'>("+ncDate+")</span></h1> \
  </p><hr /> \
  <p> \
  <strong>ISSUE TYPE:</strong><br /> \
  "+ncType+" \
  </p><p> \
  <strong>OCCURRENCE LOCATION:</strong><br /> \
  "+ncLocation+" \
  </p><p> \
  <strong>JOB NUMBER:</strong><br /> \
  "+ncJobNo+" \
  </p><p> \
  <strong>PART NUMBER:</strong><br /> \
  "+ncPartNo+" \
  </p><p> \
  <strong>LINKS:</strong><ul> \
  <li>Photo(s) = "+ncPhotos+"</li> \
  <li>Email = "+ncEmail+"</li> \
  </ul></p><p> \
  <strong>PART DESCRIPTION:</strong><br /> \
  "+ncPartDesc+" \
  </p><p> \
  <strong>FOLLOW UP:</strong> \
  "+ncEmail+" \
  </p>"; 

  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: emailRecipients,
    subject: emailSubject,
    htmlBody: emailBody
  });
}
```

The form ID is added, then the email is sent, but with all the data being pulled from one column to the left of the required one. What am I missing here?

Comment: How does `assignID` get called, exactly? What is `e` in that context? You might try logging `e` and `e.range` (for example, `Logger.log(e.range);`) to make sure you are calling `sendEmail` with the range you expect.

Comment: It's being called via an 'On form submit' trigger. I'm trying to use the Logger but I must not be using it correctly, as it's returning [object Object] and Range?

Comment: Ah- that means `e` and `Range` are somewhat complex data types that the logger can't easily print. You could try `JSON.stringify(e)` or `range.getValues()` or `range.getA1Notation()`.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not sure how to apply your latest suggestions to my script.

Comment: I mean in the `assignID` function, before calling `sendEmail`, you may want to try something like `Logger.log(e.range.getA1Notation());`. This will let you see what range of spreadsheet cells is being passed to the `sendEmail` function, which could help debug the off-by-one issue.

Comment: Ah! Very cool - this returns a log result of B55:L55.

Comment: Okay. So that means when you say `var ncID = col[0];`, you are referencing column B-- that's the first column in your range. Is that what you intended? If not, you may want to pass a different range into `sendEmail`, or reference difference columns within `sendEmail.` Good luck.

Comment: That explains why the 0 = B, but I don't know why it's doing this. Maybe due to me messing around in a linked form sheet, as @Cooper mentioned? I tried moving the ID column to column L, but then the logger shows a range of A:K. Any idea how I can define what e.range should be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When implementing a trigger, the optional parameter  “e” allows you access the event range. However, as Cooper pointed out: Google Form will put the date stamp in the first column.  Thus, the indexes of the columns will be shifted in comparison to what you expect.  So, you have to shift the indexes of the cells from which you retrieve your data accordingly.

As for your sequential ID number, I would suggest that you implement it in an empty cell, in an additional new column.

For example: 
You can use column 13 for it (knowing that column 1 is reserved for the time stamp and columns 2 to 12 are filled with the data from the form submission).

```
  sheetID.getRange(colID,13).setValue(colID)
```

Alternatively, you could also work with the range of the sheet, rather than the event range - to avoid the column offset. It would look like this:

```
 function assignID(e) {      
  var sheetID = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  var colID =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getLastRow()

  sheetID.getRange(colID,13).setValue(colID)
  var range =sheetID.getRange(colID,1,1, sheetID.getMaxColumns())
  SpreadsheetApp.flush()
  sendEmail(range)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is likely that `sendEmail` is not being called with the range you expect. You can debug the issue by inserting log statements, for instance `Logger.log(range.getA1Notation())`, at top of the `sendEmail` function.

If the range is not what you intended, try calling calling the function with a different, more explicit, range-- rather than the one attached to `e`.

I believe you are trying to select the bottommost (most recent) row in the sheet, including an additional column not included in `e`. If that is the case, this might work for you:

```
function assignID(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var colID = sheet.getLastRow();

  sheet.getRange(colID, 1).setValue(colID);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();

  var eventRow = e.range.getRow();
  var eventNumCols = e.range.getNumColumns();

  var startRow = eventRow;
  var startCol = 1;
  var numRows = 1;
  var numCols = eventNumCols + 1;

  var range = sheet.getRange(startRow, startCol, numRows, numCols);
  sendEmail(range);
}

function sendEmail(range) {
  var values = range.getValues();
  var row = values[0];

  var ncID = row[0];
  var ncDate = row[1];
  var ncType = row[2];
  var ncLocation = row[3];
  var ncJobNo = row[4];
  var ncPartNo = row[5];
  var ncPartDesc = row[6];
  var ncPartQty = row[7];
  var ncDetails = row[8];
  var ncPhotos = row[9];
  var ncProposedSol = row[10];
  var ncEmail = row[11];

  ...

}
```

---

Additionally, you may want to look into the [templated HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates) capabilities, which lets you put most of the HTML in its own file instead of composing it using JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you for this, unfortunately, it only shows me the top row instead of the latest entry. How then was sendEmail getting the correct range on its own?

Comment: I see. The event object, `e`, was just the range for the newest row of data, not a larger range. Also: `values[0]` is actually a row, not a column, as it was previously named. I edited the answer with one more suggestion. It's not tested-- you may need to tweak those values (startRow, startCol, numRows, numCols) a little, but this approach hopefully gives you the flexibility to accomplish what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would be a lot better off to use an [onFormSubmit()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit) trigger.  But keep in mind that the Google Form is always going to put the Date in the first column.  So I would recommend that you not modify the form linked sheets.

The data that you would require for the email will be in either e.values or e.namedValues and by using the onFormSubmit from within the Spreadsheet is that you can always guarantee that your getting the correct data even when form submissions are coming in fast from other users of the form.

Comment: 'On form submit' is triggering the function assignID, but yes, I did modify the form linked sheet by inserting another column before the date column. How would I use e.values or e.namedValues?

Comment: Is it okay to add additional data to the linked form sheet as long as I don't mess with the original column layout?

Comment: I know some people do it but I think it's a bad idea.  I thinks it's better to just leave it alone.  What's the big deal?  You have access to well over 200 sheets.

Comment: Excellent point, I'm just not sure how to have another sheet receive this information, add an ID to it, and then email it from there.